# Форматирование даты

Tags: sql, mysql

При реализации CRUD встает проблема преобразования даты туда и обратно, так как представление пользователя - **dd.mm.yyyy**, а представление MySQL - **yyyy-mm-dd**. Можно ли заставить MySQL хранить `DATE` в виде  **dd.mm.yyyy**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а что если сохранить дату в мускуле как varchar? :) Все ограничения снимаются.. правда теряются вкусности мускулевских функций по работе с датами.. Но может вам это и не нужно вовсе.. )

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить - нет. Но можно заставить выводить  в удобном формате.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2011-11-08",'%d.%m.%Y');
```

результат

```
08.11.2011
```

Comment: Ну это я знаю вопрос в другом снять с скрипта обязанности по преобразованиям. Можно ли заставить mysql делать автоматические преобразования с датой? Хранит пускай как ему вздумается. А то какой смысл базы если она хранит данные как ей хочется?!

Answer (score 0):

Да хранить можно в любом виде, кстати в INT формате хранить дату много проще и работать с ней. пусть и преобразовать немного нужно, но удобнее и быстрее.

Comment: Преобразовывать прям в мускуле можно?

Comment: нет уже когда из мускула взял данные в INT их в php допустим переделываешь в нужный тебе формат.

Что-то вроде timestamp только весит в БД меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего хранить в datetime, в стандартном формате mysql. Когда принимаете данные с БД - выполняете преобразование с помощью date() к нужному виду. Когда сохраняете - выполняете обратное преобразование. Существенно быстродействие не понизит этот способ, зато сохранятся все возможности работы с датами в БД.
Другой вариант - хранить метку времени в INT, но опять же - понадобится преобразование, и теряются возможности работы с датой в mysql.